# Android form wizard library suggestions

Tags: android, forms, wizard

We're building a large Android tablet app that will include a data collection component (similar to ie ODK, eMocha, etc). I had thought to use a form wizard style library for this data collection component, but can't seem to find much. Am hoping not to have to do this all from scratch - any suggestions on Android form wizard libraries?

Thanks in advance,
Colin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

[Wizard pager](https://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/wizardpager)

It creates form wizards

Answer (score 0):

No libraries available as far as I'm aware.
I'm using fragments with Actionbar Sherlock and swipe.
Basically one fragment activity with a layout to contain "static" for all views and then a number of fragments, each with their own views that can be swiped to get to the next and previous screens of the wizard with the last fragment being the submit button.

This approach with the main fragment activity descended from SherlockFragmentActivity controlling the fragments makes it dead easy to maintain state accross the various fragments.

I'm using Actionbar Sherlock for backwards compatibility across Android OS versions and waiting patiently for the native Android Action bar to be added to the support library as promised in one of the Google I/O 2012 presentations on navigation.

The above approach means that there would not be a huge amount of extra work involved than any generic wizard generator would give you.

Hope that helps